CASTING integer to integer[] postgresql in UNION ALL
I am using postgresql and have a select statement on mulitple tables
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW group.all 
AS 
SELECT 'gmail'::text AS main_source,
        gmail.id,
        gmail.from,
        gmail.to,
        gmail.user_id
FROM first_group.gmail
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'yahoo'::text AS main_source,
        yahoo.id,
        yahoo.from,
        yahoo.to,
        yahoo.user_id
FROM second_group.yahoo
UNION ALL
SELECT 'outlook'::text AS main_source,
        outlook.id,
        outlook.from,
        outlook.to,
        NULL::integer AS user_id
FROM third_group.outlook

For the NULL value I now want to change it to equal participant_ids that has the data type integer[] while for all the sources user_id is integer data type.
I tried casting:

SELECT 'outlook'::text AS main_source,
        outlook.id,
        outlook.from
        outlook.to
        outlook.participant_ids::integer AS user_id
FROM third_group.outlook

But the received this error ERROR:  UNION types integer and integer[] cannot be matched 
I also tried this syntax ARRAY[outlook.participant_ids]::integer  but received an error.
I also tried changing the datatype of the column for all sources using this command and altering it for each source.
ALTER TABLE first_group.gmail
    ALTER COLUMN user_id TYPE integer[];
ALTER TABLE second_group.yahoo
    ALTER COLUMN user_id TYPE integer[];
ALTER TABLE third_group.outlook
    ALTER COLUMN user_id TYPE integer[];

But received this error ERROR:  column "user_id" cannot be cast automatically to type integer[] HINT:  You might need to specify "USING user_id::integer[]". 
This is how the table was created.
CREATE TABLE third_group.outlook(
 id integer NOT NULL
 created_at timestamp with time zone DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 participants_ids integer[]
)

The same table was created for first_group and second_group.
Is there a way to cast the datatype integer to integer[]? Or is there a way to change the data type of the column from integer to integer[]?

What result do you expect to get if the outlook.participant_ids contains multiple elements? What if it contains none?

i expect outlook.participant_ids to equal a value, an array with at least one integer value. it could also contain multiple integers

post table with create table and data (Insert INTO) and wanted result a dbfiddle helps also

HINT:  You might need to specify "USING user_id::integer[]" did you try that?

"The same table was created for first_group and second_group." No, first_group.gmail and second_group.yahoo are obviously different. Please fix your question.

I tried the HINT but received this error ERROR:  cannot cast type integer to integer[]. I looked up the syntax for the USING keyword

That's because (as both answers tell you) you need ARRAY[user_id] instead of user_id::integer[].

I looked up the syntax for the USING keyword. I got this error ERROR:  cannot alter type of a column used by a view or rule. the group.all table depends on user_id

You need to drop all depending objects (including views and foreign keys if any) and recreate after you have altered the table. That is, if you indeed want to alter the column type. I am not convinced this is the best course of action. Not enough information.

This does not directly address the original question; however, having an array of IDs, which I assume are references to IDs in other tables, is a design defect that precludes effective referential integrity enforcement.

You cannot cast an integer to an array or back. You can only wrap an integer in an array, or access an array element. You seem to be looking for
SELECT 'gmail'::text AS main_source,
        gmail.id,
        gmail.from,
        gmail.to,
        ARRAY[gmail.user_id] AS user_ids
--      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FROM first_group.gmail
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'yahoo'::text AS main_source,
        yahoo.id,
        yahoo.from,
        yahoo.to,
        ARRAY[yahoo.user_id] AS user_ids
--      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FROM second_group.yahoo
UNION ALL
SELECT 'outlook'::text AS main_source,
        outlook.id,
        outlook.from,
        outlook.to,
        outlook.participant_ids AS user_ids
FROM third_group.outlook


your suggestion above still leads toERROR: UNION types integer and integer[] cannot be matched

Really? Then please edit your question to include the table definitions (of first_group.gmail, second_group.yahoo, third_group.outlook) so that we have a [mcve] to try ourselves

Could you explain how this works for the outlook.participant_ids  SELECT 'outlook'::text AS main_source,         outlook.id,         outlook.from,         outlook.to,         outlook.participant_ids AS user_ids FROM third_group.outlook
because in your example above there is no changes being made.outlook.participant_ids  is still data type integer[] and user_ids is integer

@jSvSL The change I've made is to ARRAY[gmail.user_id] AS user_ids and ARRAY[yahoo.user_id] AS user_ids - those are the integers you need to transform into arrays so that you get an integer[] column from all the union queries.

Bergi's query works with the data types you hinted: integer for both user_id and integer[] for participant_ids. (You didn't declare properly.)
Changing the column data type from integer to integer[] works like this:
ALTER TABLE first_group.gmail
ALTER COLUMN user_id TYPE integer[] USING ARRAY[user_id];

Either way, you need an Array constructor.
Note that this produces {null} (an array with one null element) for null input. If you want a plain null instead:
ALTER TABLE first_group.gmail
ALTER COLUMN user_id TYPE integer[] USING NULLIF(ARRAY[user_id], '{null}');

